# Plot legend without line break

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am having a plot with legend entries. The entries are not really long, it would be nice to have them in a single row. The default behavior adds a line break after each entry. Furthermore, the are all centered, I would prefer left flushed.

I did not find the correct parameter for changing that. Anyone any suggestions or pointers fore me?

Comment: Are you using `pgfplots`? This is sort of impossible to answer without knowing how you created the plot and legend, so please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: I see from your other question (that I also commented on) that you are indeed using `pgfplots`. Still, my previous comment applies.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I will add an MWE the next time. sry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `legend columns` key (`-1` makes all legends to go horizontally):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={
at={(0.5,1.03)},
anchor=south}}
\begin{axis}[legend columns=-1]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,2) (1,3)};
\legend{$l_1$,$l_2$,$l_3$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]